# I can't join a Minecraft server running on the same machine

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I run a Minecraft 1.17.1 server on the same machine but when I try to connect to it I can't, while everyone else can join it. I'm connecting to localhost:"port". When the server was still in 1.16.5 it worked just fine. I have my firewall disabled.

This is the error that I get when I try to join.

[image]

I think it is some kind of client issue because when I try to use 1.17 to connect to the server (that is in 1.16) I get the same error, not the outdated one.

Comment: I don't know much about networking but try `localhost` as the address

Comment: localhost:port should work on the same machine. If the port is `25565`, you can safely omit it.

Answer (score -1):

You can either put 127.0.0.1:{port}, 192.168.1.1, localhost (try it without a port this time), or your public IP.

If that doesn't work just make sure you're using the normal launcher and have 1.17.1 (Not 1.17 it won't work).

Comment: Thank you but i get the same error if i try them(but with the difretnt ip at the end.) but if I use the 192.168.1.1 one it waits a bit and then shows the errror not like the others, and yes im in 1.17.1.

Comment: Do you have online mode as true in the properties file?